# Browser redirects to coo123.net

Tags: browser

When I open my tablets browser to yahoo it automatically redirects to coo123.net page. How do I stop that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the entry for yahoo in the host file. (It's most likely here it's happening)

Here's how:
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/edit-your-rooted-android-hosts-file-to-block-ad-servers/

Essentially:

1. Use a file manager like ES File Explorer
2. Locate the file /system/etc/hosts
3. Remove the line that says anything about yahoo
4. Save the file
5. Reboot

If it doesn't work make sure that the file has the correct permissions:

> 1. Open ES File Manager
> 2. Navigate to `/system/etc`
> 3. Locate and long-press the `hosts` file
> 4. Tap the menu button
> 5. Select **Properties**
> 6. Tap **Change** in the Permissions section
> 7. Tap the check box for Group under the **Write** column (Figure B)
> 8. Tap OK
> 9. Tap Cancel
> 10. Reboot device

(Quoted from techrepublic)

Comment: Please provide some detail or summarize what the link states please. So anybody else with a similar issue can utilize the info.

Comment: Of course - Done :-)